# Can you read a web pages sources code and covert it to a .txt file

Tags: php

Im converting a PHP file to .txt file on a local host.

i am using file_get_contents at the moment to write my php file to a txt file the only problem i am having is that it is not reading in the php variables that i pull from my SQL file in this page. It renders perfectly on screen but when it writes it to a txt file all my variables are missing

So i was wondering if there was a way i could write the source code of that web page (the outcome once the page has been loaded) to a text file so it read in all the variables?

This is my SQL line which gets the CompleteDate this is in a separate sql.php file which gets called at the start of certificates.php

```
if (isset($_GET['CompleteDate'])) {$CompleteDate = $_GET['CompleteDate'];};
```

In Certificates.php I echo out the $CompleteDate which shows perfectly when i view it through my local host

```
<h3><div class="info">Date </div><?php echo $CompleteDate ; ?></h3>
```

Then you click a button to convert that page into a . txt file

```
<form action = "convert.php">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value =" convert" class="pdfButton">
</form>
```

When you click the button it calls this code from convert.php

```
<?php $test = file_get_contents("http://localhost/test/Certificates.php");  file_put_contents("test.txt","$test");?>
```

When i check my .txt file it outputs "Date:" Then there is a blank space where the $CompletedDate variable should be

**Why is it not reading in my SQL variables from my php page when it displays perfectly in my browser??**

I am quite new to this so i assume it is something i am doing wrong.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  That call to `file_get_contents()` should be getting the result of processing that PHP page, so it should be getting HTML.  (Unless the local web server isn't running PHP correctly?)  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: it is reading in the html of the php file but not the php. is it because it has been put into a button, so when you click a button it runs a separate php file with just the above code in ?? Sorry i should of made that clear in my question

Comment: What do you mean by "reading the PHP"?  Do you expect the web server to return *the PHP code*?  That's not how PHP works on a web server.  The code isn't executed by *the browser*, it's executed by the server and the *result* is sent to the browser.  So when you read that URL, you're getting the *result* of the PHP code.  Not the code itself.  (Just imagine a world in which anybody going to your website could *see the server-side code*.)

Comment: I mean where i have <?php echo $Datecompleted ?> it is just returnign a blank space and not showing the variable $Datecompleted (10-10-15) but it outputs correctly when i view it through my local host jus tnot when i write it to a text file

Comment: Then it would seem that the `$Datecompleted` variable doesn't contain a value at that time.  Should it?  Where does it get that value?  Nobody here can help with code we can't see.

Comment: My apologise, i have updated my question with the whole process and what it calls and when. Im sure it is something i am doing wrong as i am quite new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value comes from the query string:

```
$CompleteDate = $_GET['CompleteDate']
```

But when you invoke the page, you don't provide anything on the query string:

```
file_get_contents("http://localhost/test/Certificates.php")
```

So there's no value for the code to use.  In order to get a value from the query string, you have to provide a value:

```
file_get_contents("http://localhost/test/Certificates.php?CompleteDate=someValue")
```